# How is "How long before that thing is ready?" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

In a TV show, a character said, "How long before that thing is ready?" I want to know: How is that sentence correct? I mean, if I were to say the same thing I would have said, "How long would it take for that thing to get ready?" I  dont know if I am compeletely correct or not but still I never would have said the sentence that the character had said.

Also, please tell me: **What are some other ways to say the same thing?**

Comment: When asking grammar questions, it's useful to use proper spelling. That includes using a capital for the first person [I and not i] and putting in the apostrophes: I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Spoken English can have grammar that is not like traditional grammar for written texts or formal spoken texts. Often, in spoken English, their is truncation or shortening:

How long [will it be] before that thing is ready? 
becomes just leaves out the first verb.
It is perfectly acceptable.

Also, "to get ready" is for people: He got ready for work early in the morning.
"to be ready" is for people or things. For things, to be ready might apply to having some object repaired: How long [will it be] before that thing [some object] is ready.

Comment: Or: "How long [will it take] to get that thing ready?"

Comment: Sure, to get something ready.